# Principal Log and multivalued considerations for $(1+z)^a$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Say that $z=0$ and that $a$ is a complex exponent. What does $1^a$ really mean? Obviously it's not the same as if $a$ was an integer, but how does the multivalued property of principal branch $\log$ play into this? Would we need to attach an $i\arg(0)$ to it? And if I were to take derivatives, are there special property considerations?

Comment: The principal branch is $\log(z)=\log|z|+i\arg z$ with $-\pi<\arg z\leq \pi$. Thus, $\log(1)=\log|1|+i\arg(1)=0+i0=0$. Thus, $1^a=\exp(a\log 1)=\exp(a\cdot0)=\exp(0)=1$.

Comment: I guess my question is that if I define the domain of $(1+z)^a$ to be the same as the principal branch of Log, then would this result $1^a$ be equivalent to as if $a$ was just an integer?

Assuming $(1+z)^a = e^{alog(1+z)}$

Comment: Why don't you write $z$ instead of $(1+z)$? So $z^a=\exp(a\log z)$. But anyway see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I was taught, if $a = u + iv$ and $w = re^{i\theta}$ then

$w^a = \left[re^{i\theta}\right]^{u + iv}.$

Here, for simplicity, I am assuming that you are selecting $\theta$ to be the *principal* argument, which implies that $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi.$

So, you have

$$w^a = e^{\log(r)[u + iv]} \times e^{i\theta(u + iv)}$$

$$= e^{[u\log(r) - v\theta]} \times e^{i[v\log(r) + u\theta]}. \tag1 $$

When $z = 1 + i(0)$, you have that $r = 1$ and $\theta = 0$.

As suggested, you could alternatively construe $\theta$ to be $2n\pi ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z}$.  Each separate value for $n$ would yield a different computation in (1) above.

Therefore, the adoption of the convention that $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$ seems reasonable, since some convention is needed to remove ambiguity around the expression in (1).

Anyway, with $r = 1,$ and $\theta = 0$, you have that $\log(r) = 0.$

This implies that regardless of the value of $a = u + iv$, because $w = 1$, (1) above will evaluate to

$$e^0 \times e^{i0} = 1.$$

---

> And if I were to take derivatives, are there special property considerations?

Good question, which I do not know the answer to.